# Как расположить элементы массива в порядке возрастания или убывания

Tags: javascript, jquery

у меня есть массив с объектами у каждого объекта есть второй параметр с числом
мне нужна чтоб в массиве первый объект был с наименьшим числом во втором параметре а последний наоборот был объект с наибольшим числовым значением во втором параметре надеюсь вы поняли код объекта не скидываю потому-что там трудно что-то разобрать он очень большой спасибо на перёд)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В jquery есть функция сортировки, погугли

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как расположить элементы массива в порядке возрастания или убывания

Первый элемент вложенного массива строка, второй строка типа цифры.

Пример сортировки такого вложенного массива:

```js
var months = [
  ['March', '23'],
  ['Jan', '154'],
  ['Feb', '1020'],
  ['Dec', '8']
];
months.sort(function(a, b) {
  // Преобразуем в число для сравнения
  return Number.parseInt(a[1]) - Number.parseInt(b[1]);
});
console.log(months);
```

---

[sort док](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)